# Swift for GUI applications in ubuntu anytime soon?

Tags: swift, user-interface, ubuntu, cross-platform, compatibility

Is there any planning to tighten the integration between swift and Ubuntu allowing swift to run GUI application on Ubuntu with the same code using for macOS?

Comment: Using the same code as for OS X sounds lovely, but it would probably require open-sourcing the Cocoa framework...well, unless someone does something cool with GNUstep. More likely would be bindings for GTK+, Qt or some other widget toolkit, which would still be very useful.